# Find Sub-string that create whole string by repetation

Tags: string

I have string "hrhrhrhrhr".

I want to find smallest sub-string of t such that we can make whole string by appending that sub-string in itself several time.

in this example i can make string "hrhrhrhrhr" by four time appending of "hr" with itself.

how to find this kind of substring?
fox example,
"abcabcabc" then  "abc" is answer.

"ttttttt"  ->  "t"  is answer.

"abcd"  -> "abcd" is answer.

which algorithm or specific method i should use?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take a look at string matching/search algorithms. Particularly, if you use KMP ([Knuth-Morris Pratt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)) algorithm to search the string in itself, the lookup table would yield the pattern. In addition, the highest number in the table would give you the end character of the substring you are searching for (if the string is indeed composed of the repetition of one substring).